# Why is $\int_0^1 x^x \ln(x) \space dx = -\int_0^1 x^x \space dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-writing, exponential-function

Why is 
$\int_0^1 x^x \cdot \ln(x) \space dx = -\int_0^1 x^x \space dx$

If I enter these two integrals in Wolfram Alpha I numerically get the same result, but I couldn't find out why (I tried out some substitutions and integration by parts).

I've come across this problem in an exercise where I have to prove that
$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy)^{xy} \space dx \space dy = \int_0^1 x^{x} \space dx$

Comment: Try to find the derivative of $x^x$ then you'll see something which relates your integrals.

Comment: To add on to Zacky's point: Consider $\int_0^1f'(x) dx$, where $f(x)=x^x$, and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. (Note that you'll have to compute $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x$ for one half of this.)

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$(x^x)' =  x^x + x^x\ln x  $$
Then, with $\int_0^1 d(x^x)=0$

$$\int_0^1 x^x \ln x \space dx = -\int_0^1 x^x \space dx $$

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to set this up to be integration by parts, i.e. to find reasonable $f,g$ such that $f'(x) g(x)=x^x \ln(x)$ and $f(x) g'(x)=x^x$? The result that you get looks suspiciously similar to integration by parts...

Comment: @Ian - it’s an interesting question. I’m unsure how to recast it

Comment: @Ian - Figured out. $\int_0^1 x^x \ln x dx = \int_0^1 e^xd(x^x e^{-x})dx$